# Why didn't the British Ministry of Magic call on their foreign counterparts to help fight in the war against Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

I am just curious. It was a Huge, destructive and a famous war.

Ministry of Magic could have helped them, but why did it not help?

Please help.

Comment: A few of your questions have been closed as duplicates recently. It might be worth checking the site more carefully before posting to make sure that a question hasn’t been asked before. That said, please don’t be discouraged that some of your questions have been closed as duplicates! Duplicates can actually be very good for the site, in moderation. They can be helpful for helping other people with different search terms find the answer they need.